# Minecraft Command Block keeps killing me

Tags: minecraft-commands

I was working on a build in a superflat world in Minecraft 1.14.2 but the slimes kept annoying me. I had forgotten that you can set it so that entities do not spawn, so I tried using a command block next to the build to keep killing slime blocks. I activated it, and the game instantly killed me, saying that I "fell out of the world." I cannot get back to my project without instantly being killed by the command block, and I really do not want to restart the project. I do not remember the coordinates of the block, and it kills me before I can even see it. Now I am in 1.14.3, and I thought that something would change, but it didn't. I tried using the command that nullifies command blocks, but it didn't work. I have gone through multiple posts of things like this happening, but nothing seems to work. Please help me!!!

Comment: Set up a server, copy the world, turn command blocks off in the options, find and delete the block, copy the world back.

Comment: if this was in bedrock I would've simply said: "Just disable cheats and the problem would disappear" but this is Minecraft Java edition so that won't work.

Answer (score -1):

A drastic method will be to go to a version where command blocks do not exist (e.g. 1.3), and convert it back to 1.14.3, and then the command block should be gone, or at least stopped running. Some problems of this will be that blocks that are not in 1.3 will also be gone. Make sure you back up the world first in case something goes wrong.

P.S. I have not tested this and I am saying this out of my imagination.

Comment: This will cause a lot of damage to the world.

Comment: This will not work, because 1.13+ worlds loaded in 1.12.2  or older will just regenerate the world because save format is not compatible